# Why button is displaying the wrong color?

Tags: java, android-studio, button

This button is displaying a purple color and its XML code is

[image]

```
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="141dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="142dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_login"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvCreateAccount"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

"@drawable/btn_login" is a shape I created -

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:shape="rectangle">


    <solid android:color="#71D775">
    </solid>
    <corners android:radius="66dp">
    </corners>



</shape>
```

And this is how it looks like, [image: just a light green arounded rectangle]

Comment: Can you check the background tint of your layout?

Comment: ```android:backgroundTint="#FFF"|

    android:foregroundTint="#FFF" ```
This is it

Comment: As you get more programming experience you'll learn that, for example, it's not so much that "the button is displaying the wrong color" as it is "I've incorrectly applied color to the button".  It's been many years since I've thought, "I found a bug in Java!"  I now know that I'm my greatest source of my own problems :)

Comment: if my answer answers your question then please mark it as accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, you need to set the app:backgroundTint to null.
Like so:

```
app:backgroundTint="@null"
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because the default `MaterialButton` style overrides `backgroundTint`.

So if we are using a custom `android:background`, we have to make sure to null out `backgroundTint`. We can achieve it by any of the following way:

Add any of these line to your button XML.

```
app:backgroundTint="@null"
```

OR

```
app:backgroundTint="@empty"
```